# Reading parts of DOM PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to read certains parts from an website but i am unable to display it properly and its not grabbing the correct parts, instead its just showing all of it (the whole page) and not the objects i've selected.

This is the page i am trying to copy from. http://www.jabbithole.com/classes/engineer

What i want is the image, spell name and type as 3 variables so i can put them into an array named "spells".

```
$items = array('engineer');
foreach($items as $key => $value) {

            $url = 'http://www.jabbithole.com/classes/'.$value;     
            $html = file_get_contents($url);            
            $dom = new domDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);         
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   
            $info = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');    
            $trs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

            $spells = array();

            foreach($trs as $tr) {  
                foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $row) {  
                    foreach($row->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
                        $class = $link->getAttribute('class');  
                        if($class == 'icon')
                        {
                            $img = $link->getAttribute('src');                      
                            print_r($img);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            $name = $link->nodeValue;                   
                            print_r($name);
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
}
```

The Mark up What i am trying to get it to read

```html
<table class="datalist dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="left">Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th class="left int-sort">Source</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/mode-eradicate-47866">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer eradication mode.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_eradication_mode.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/mode-eradicate-47866">Mode: Eradicate</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Innate</td>
      <td>Class innate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/mode-provoke-47881">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer survival mode.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_survival_mode.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/mode-provoke-47881">Mode: Provoke</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Innate</td>
      <td>Class innate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/pulse-blast-42276">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer pulse blast.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_pulse_blast.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/pulse-blast-42276">Pulse Blast</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/electrocute-41276">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer electrocute.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_electrocute.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/electrocute-41276">Electrocute</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/artillery-bot-42814">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer artillery bot.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_artillery_bot.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/artillery-bot-42814">Artillerybot</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/quick-burst-41477">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer quick burst.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_quick_burst.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/quick-burst-41477">Quick Burst</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/energy-auger-34426">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer energy trail.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_energy_trail.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/energy-auger-34426">Energy Auger</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/bio-shell-41341">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer bioshell.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_bioshell.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/bio-shell-41341">Bio Shell</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/mortar-strike-41543">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer mortar strike.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_mortar_strike.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/mortar-strike-41543">Mortar Strike</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/unstable-anomaly-34669">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer anomaly launcher.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_anomaly_launcher.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/unstable-anomaly-34669">Unstable Anomaly</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/target-acquisition-38036">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer target acquistion.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_target_acquistion.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/target-acquisition-38036">Target Acquisition</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 18 AMP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/bolt-caster-34836">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer bolt caster.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_bolt_caster.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/bolt-caster-34836">Bolt Caster</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Assault</td>
      <td>Level 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/bruiser-bot-42894">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer bruiser bot.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_bruiser_bot.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/bruiser-bot-42894">Bruiserbot</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/flak-cannon-41426">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer flak cannon.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_flak_cannon.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/flak-cannon-41426">Flak Cannon</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/hyper-wave-41275">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer hyper wave.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_hyper_wave.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/hyper-wave-41275">Hyper Wave</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/unsteady-miasma-41484">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer give em gas.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_give_em_gas.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/unsteady-miasma-41484">Unsteady Miasma</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/feedback-41864">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer feedback.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_feedback.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/feedback-41864">Feedback</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/disruptive-module-41815">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer disruptive mod.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_disruptive_mod.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/disruptive-module-41815">Disruptive Module</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 18 AMP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/ricochet-41429">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer ricochet.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_ricochet.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/ricochet-41429">Ricochet</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/shock-pulse-42585">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer shock pulse.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_shock_pulse.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/shock-pulse-42585">Shock Pulse</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/particle-ejector-34658">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer particule ejector.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_particule_ejector.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/particle-ejector-34658">Particle Ejector</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/thresher-52133">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer thresher.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_thresher.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/thresher-52133">Thresher</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Support</td>
      <td>Level 31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/zap-41438">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer zap.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_zap.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/zap-41438">Zap</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/urgent-withdrawal-34522">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer urgent withdrawal.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_urgent_withdrawal.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/urgent-withdrawal-34522">Urgent Withdrawal</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/recursive-matrix-42572">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer recursive matrix.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_recursive_matrix.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/recursive-matrix-42572">Recursive Matrix</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/diminisher-bot-42833">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer diminisher bot.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_diminisher_bot.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/diminisher-bot-42833">Diminisherbot</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/repair-bot-42810">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer repair bot.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_repair_bot.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/repair-bot-42810">Repairbot</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 18 AMP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/shatter-impairment-42803">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer shatter impairment.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_shatter_impairment.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/shatter-impairment-42803">Shatter Impairment</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/volatile-injection-41756">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer volatile injection.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_volatile_injection.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/volatile-injection-41756">Volatile Injection</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/code-red-41623">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer code red.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_code_red.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/code-red-41623">Code Red</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/personal-defense-unit-44471">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer personal defense unit.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_personal_defense_unit.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/personal-defense-unit-44471">Personal Defense Unit</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a class="icon" href="/spells/obstruct-vision-51605">
          <img alt="Icon skillengineer shock wave.36" src="/assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_shock_wave.36.png" />
        </a> <a href="/spells/obstruct-vision-51605">Obstruct Vision</a>
      </td>
      <td class="center">Utility</td>
      <td>Level 31</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
<?PHP
    //include library
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

    $items = array('engineer');
    foreach($items as $key => $value) {
        $url = 'http://www.jabbithole.com/classes/'.$value;
        //read html from server and create html_dom object
        $html = file_get_html($url);

        //find the table using css selectors
        $table = $html->find('#tab-abi table', 0);

        $results = array();
        $first = true;
        //iterate each tr
        foreach($table->find('tr') as $element){
            //skip first tr (table header)
            if($first){
                $first = false;
                continue;
            }
            //extract data
            $results[] = array(
                'image' => $element->find('img',0)->src,
                'name' => $element->find('.name',0)->plaintext,
                'class' => $element->find('.center',0)->plaintext
            );
        }
    }

    print_r($results);
?>
```

The library allows you to query the DOM using CSS selectors (jQuery style) and also supports malformed HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone beat me to it, but here's an alternate way of doing the same thing. This time with core PHP functions. You can parse the document using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), then grab the requested contents with some simple [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) queries:

```
// Load the HTML into a DOM document (@ = suppress a bunch of warnings)
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.jabbithole.com/classes/engineer');

// Create a DOM XPath object
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Find all <tr> tags within the first <table> element, skipping the first <tr>
// which is the header
$trs = $xpath->query('//table[1]//tr[position() > 1]');

// Loop through found <tr> tags    
$abilities = [];
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    // Name is value of first <td> inside <tr>
    // Type is value of second <td> inside <tr>
    // Image is the src attribute of the <img> tag inside <tr>
    $name  = $xpath->query('.//td[1]',    $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $type  = $xpath->query('.//td[2]',    $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $image = $xpath->query('.//img/@src', $tr)->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // Add to result array
    $abilities[] = array(
        'name'  => trim($name),
        'type'  => trim($type),
        'image' => trim($image),
    );
}

print_r($abilities);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mode: Eradicate
            [type] => Innate
            [image] => /assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_eradication_mode.36.png
        )

    ...

    [31] => Array
        (
            [name] => Obstruct Vision
            [type] => Utility
            [image] => /assets/icons/icon_skillengineer_shock_wave.36.png
        )

)
```